# JavaScript Game TypeMismatchError

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game in HTML/JavaScript.
The game is going to be like MineCraft, but 2D.
The code that's not working is for rendering the blocks.
All the variables are set, but not shown in the code I'm giving you.
This code was working, but now its not

```
for(var key in blocks){
    context.drawImage(blocks[key].img, blocks[key].x, blocks[key].y, size, size);
    if(collision(blocks[key], player)) context.fillText("COLLISION", 200, 20);
}
```

The TypeMismatchError is in the `context.drawImage(blocks[key].img, blocks[key].x, blocks[key].y, size, size);`

Answer (score 2):

This error can appear when the first argument passed to the `context.drawImage` method is incorrect. Only Image objects, canvas, or videos elements can be passed as first parameter.

Be sure that your image is loaded before you draw it onto the canvas using drawImage. In the example below, notice the img.grass.onload method. It ensures you that the image asset is available for drawing :

```
var img = {};
img.grass = new Image();
img.grass.src = "grass.jpg";
img.grass.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
      context.drawImage(img.grass, j*50, i*50, 50, 50);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it is an image object.

Comment: here is the code for making the image.     img.grass = new Image();
img.grass.src = "img/grass.png"; block = img.grass; var asd = {
   x:Math.round(player.x / size) * size,
   y:Math.round(player.y / size) * size-10,
   img:block,
   id:Math.random() * 100
  };
  blocks[asd.id] = asd;    HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: Check the `onload` method in the edited answer.

Comment: thanks, but i have other images, like dirt, stone, planks etc. one of the first things is loading the images, and it works for other things which use the same image, but it does not have this error.

Comment: Have you another js error displayed ? Can you check the value returned by blocks[key].img in the loop (with console.log) ? Did you checked if the image is loaded before using drawImage ? If the grass image is bigger than the others, this may explain why you got this error only for this image. The browser didn't have enough time for loaded the grass image while the others images are loaded at the right time during the script execution.

Comment: ok. i'll check the value in console.log. thanks

Comment: I checked it, and the value was    <img src="img/grass.png"></img> which is correct

Comment: any more help?? here is a link to the game: http://teacherofthings.webege.com/games/game.html